# Remove file names from Finder right-click menu

Tags: macos, finder, customization, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

This is a small annoyance I've always had with the Finder.

When you right-click on items, *some* of the context menu's menu items then repeat the file name in their titles.

> Compress "some_file_name.txt"
>   ...
>   Quick Look "some_file_name.txt"
>   ...
>   Copy "some_file_name.txt"

For long file names, the context menu gets comically large.

This makes using submenus such as "Open With" and "Services" harder, as you need to precisely mouse a greater distance to enter the submenu.

It's also just annoying and overly busy UI. I don't need to be reminded 3 times which file I right clicked. Just give me a nice clean menu. I'm able to `Get Info` or `Rename` items without knowing the file name... I think I can manage for `Compress` as well.

**Is there any way to remove the file name from these menu items?**

I want it to just say `Compress`, `Quick Look`, and `Copy`.

[image]